# AttributeError: type object has no attribute for a django model

Tags: django-models

Here are the models:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    login = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
class Course(models.Model):
    semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher.login, through='TeacherCourse')
    credits = models.IntegerField()
    numberEnrolled = models.IntegerField()
    nomenclature = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    lectures = models.IntegerField()

class TeacherCourse(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher.login, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    allotedLectures = models.IntegerField()
```

Just added these to fresh project and tried to runserver. I'm getting the following:

AttributeError: type object 'Teacher' has no attribute 'login'

I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later found your bug from Uday Bhatye's answer:

```
teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher.login, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

is a syntax error in django.

You should do:

```
teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And to reference the login status of teachers assigned to a particular `TeacherCourse`:

```
teachercourse = TeacherCourse.objects.filter(id=teachercourse_id).select_related('teacher')
login_status = course.teacher.login
```

Hits the database once with `select_related` and fetches the login status of all teachers assigned to the `TeacherCourse`.

Comment: I think, even if I run the server without migrating, it should tell me to migrate and run server successfully, provided there are no errors. Tried your suggestion. Getting the same error on makemigrations.

Comment: Yes. It is indeed a syntax error in django. Thanks for pointing out clearly. Here the login attribute is the loginid of the teacher and hence is the primary key in teacher model. I'm using already available ldap of our institute to authenticate teachers.

Answer (score 0):

As the login field in teacher model is already declared as primary key, I need not reference it in the other two models as Teacher.login. Only referencing as Teacher suffices.